# Determining whether `contextmenu` command actually opened a context menu

Tags: contextmenu, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a webextension which has a listener for `contextmenu` events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

This event is fired when the user tries to open a context menu (usually by right-clicking) on some element.  But for the event to be fired, it is not necessary that any (dom-based) context menu actually opens (you'll usually see some context menu, but it may be application/system level and not related to the dom).

Is there any way to determine programmatically whether a context menu actually opened?

Answer (score 1):

We can utilize the way events are dispatched, which happens in two phases: capturing (the event "descends" the DOM tree from `window` to the target element) and bubbling (the event "ascends" back up to `window`).

So the menu will be shown if the event wasn't canceled when it has "bubbled" back to `window`.

```js
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
  if (e.isTrusted && !e.defaultPrevented) {
    console.log('will show the menu now');
  }
});
```

Note that the dispatch process may be stopped by some other script via `event.stopPropagation()` so the event will never be dispatched on `window` in the bubbling phase. If you want to detect this, you can listen to the event in the capturing phase and start a timer:

```js
let timer;
window.addEventListener('contextmenu',
  e => { if (e.isTrusted) timer = setTimeout(detectCanceledMenu, 0, e.target); },
  true);

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', () => clearTimeout(timer));

function detectCanceledMenu(el) {
  console.log('the menu was canceled');
}
```

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your answer.  I've been unable to get back to this project but I will look into what you suggest as soon as I am able.